# Remote Connection like Browser Toolbox

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to interact with another open profile, which is a seperate process. Browser Toolbox does this. I was wondering how can I re-simulate this behavior? Without the prompt asking for "allow remote connection"?

My goal is to (1) find all open firefox process, (2) access each of its xpcom and figure out the profile name, (3) and if its a profile name Im interested in, Ill focus its most recent window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but I'm getting somewhere by tracing it in MXR:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/devtools/framework/toolbox-process-window.js#11

```
11 let { debuggerSocketConnect, DebuggerClient } =
12   Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm", {});
13 let { ViewHelpers } =
14   Cu.import("resource:///modules/devtools/ViewHelpers.jsm", {});
15 
16 /**
17  * Shortcuts for accessing various debugger preferences.
18  */
19 let Prefs = new ViewHelpers.Prefs("devtools.debugger", {
20   chromeDebuggingHost: ["Char", "chrome-debugging-host"],
21   chromeDebuggingPort: ["Int", "chrome-debugging-port"]
22 });
23 
24 let gToolbox, gClient;
25 
26 function connect() {
27   window.removeEventListener("load", connect);
28   // Initiate the connection
29   let transport = debuggerSocketConnect(
30     Prefs.chromeDebuggingHost,
31     Prefs.chromeDebuggingPort
32   );
33   gClient = new DebuggerClient(transport);
34   gClient.connect(() => {
35     let addonID = getParameterByName("addonID");
36 
37     if (addonID) {
38       gClient.listAddons(({addons}) => {
39         let addonActor = addons.filter(addon => addon.id === addonID).pop();
40         openToolbox({ addonActor: addonActor.actor, title: addonActor.name });
41       });
42     } else {
43       gClient.listTabs(openToolbox);
44     }
45   });
46 }
47
```

I ran the profile and it looks like the pref `..-host` is `localhost` and `..-port` is `6080`. I'm not sure how this helps target a specific profile though. Maybe on start of the browser toolbox it opened port 6080 to the opener profile. I'm not sure, but if its true, then you'll have to run code from within the target profile to open a port maybe.

Totally not sure though.

But port is opened here:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/devtools/framework/ToolboxProcess.jsm#107

```
106 
107 BrowserToolboxProcess.prototype = {
108   /**
109    * Initializes the debugger server.
110    */
111   _initServer: function() {
112     dumpn("Initializing the chrome toolbox server.");
113 
114     if (!this.loader) {
115       // Create a separate loader instance, so that we can be sure to receive a
116       // separate instance of the DebuggingServer from the rest of the devtools.
117       // This allows us to safely use the tools against even the actors and
118       // DebuggingServer itself, especially since we can mark this loader as
119       // invisible to the debugger (unlike the usual loader settings).
120       this.loader = new DevToolsLoader();
121       this.loader.invisibleToDebugger = true;
122       this.loader.main("devtools/server/main");
123       this.debuggerServer = this.loader.DebuggerServer;
124       dumpn("Created a separate loader instance for the DebuggerServer.");
125 
126       // Forward interesting events.
127       this.debuggerServer.on("connectionchange", this.emit.bind(this));
128     }
129 
130     if (!this.debuggerServer.initialized) {
131       this.debuggerServer.init();
132       this.debuggerServer.addBrowserActors();
133       dumpn("initialized and added the browser actors for the DebuggerServer.");
134     }
135 
136     this.debuggerServer.openListener(Prefs.chromeDebuggingPort);
137 
138     dumpn("Finished initializing the chrome toolbox server.");
139     dumpn("Started listening on port: " + Prefs.chromeDebuggingPort);
140   },
141
```

Comment: Oh that looks like how it works. Ideally I'm looking for a one way thing, where I don't have to run code from the other profile to allow connect from some other.